# Bash autocomplete in Terminal stops working after a while

Tags: high-sierra, bash, auto-complete

Bash allows auto-completion using the tab key:

If you type `cd ~/D` on Terminal, followed by the Tab key, you ear a beep, but if you follow by a second Tab key, the Terminal display the suggestions `Desktop/ Documents/ Downloads/`. If you type "e" followed by Tab, the auto completion displays `cd ~/Desktop/`, that is (here) the only folder in Home folder who begins with "De".

For whatever reason it stops to work for me after a while using Terminal or Iterm2. How can I diagnose and fix this?

Comment: What is the value of the various `bash` variables controlling tab completion (check the man page) after it stops working?